# How to get the returned value for a Mocked method in C# unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to get the result from a Mocked method in C# unit tests. The method being mocked looks like:

`var result = await _postingClient.DeletePostingsAsync(lookupIds);`

And what I have in the unit test so far is:

`postingClient.Setup(c => c.DeletePostingAsync(It.Is<Guid>(g => g == postingId && null == expectedException)))`

Is there a way to get what the value of result should be?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Moq ? In that case have a look into `.ReturnsAsync`

Comment: Usually Moq returns `default(T)` or something like `Task.FromResult(default(T))` and user should set up desired return via `Returns/ReturnsAsync` call on result of `Setup`